# How to web scrape database of users w/o API?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

For fun, I've learnt since last night how to do basic web scraping, using Python's urllib, urllib2, cookie-jar, and BeautifulSoup. It only took a bit, but I've figured out how to get all information from each user's profile that I need (OKCupid to be exact). However, I've only figured out how to do so, and have no idea how to go through a public database of users without an API from the site.

Is there any easy way to do so? Thanks.

Comment: I think the way you have figured out already is as close to "easy" as you are likely to get.  Maybe [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) can make it easier?

Comment: Do you know how to get a list of users (a page at a time, or whatever) in your web browser? If so, ultimately it's just a matter of figuring out how to do the same thing from a scraper. For some sites, this is just a matter of doing a very open-ended search (and possibly dealing with duplicates—e.g., no matter how you page through the users on this site, they're going to re-sort before you can get through the whole list). For other sites, it may not be possible at all. Also, some sites have an interface specifically for search-engine spiders you might want to look into.

Comment: Also, have you considered checking to see whether they _have_ an API, or would be willing to open one up? A lot of services won't think it's very "friendly" for you to automate paging through thousands of pages, and might prefer to give you a better way to do it. (Especially if you're going to distribute your code to multiple people!)

Comment: So, do you think entering a search of just '' would technically match every user on the site? I mean, they have to have SOME sort of limit, and searches are typically based off username, but the "dating" searches are based off of stats.

Comment: And trust me, I searched my ass off for one, there's been tons of chatter about it in their forum but they've still never put out anything for the public (that an hour of Googling could find, anyway).

Comment: @Befall, any news? You'll probably also require the `multiprocessing` module along with multiple coordinated scraper user accounts for high-throughput concurrent scraping. These will store the scraped data in a single well-indexed database. This can get super hairy, but it is mandatory if you want to scrape everyone and not just a small sample. Remember to record the time of each entry, and prevent duplicate unexpired scrapes. It's possible that the website will throttle or block your IP for excessive traffic, so I wouldn't use my own IP. Using an anonymizing VPN may be an option.

Comment: @Befall, I suggest you start this at Monday 11 pm Eastern, and aim to finish no later than Tuesday 7 am Eastern. You can asymptotically estimate how close you are to finishing by measuring a moving-average ratio of scraped:encountered targets. When the security staff come in at 8:30 am to deal with the red flags, your work should've been completed. Maybe they won't even ban you.

Comment: @Befall, there was a famous news report earlier this month of accounts getting banned after exceeding 1000 profile scrapes in 24 hours. I guess this means that site account creation will also have to be automated, even if it has a captcha.